# MPEG-DASH support on VLC Player

Tags: video-streaming, media-player, manifest, vlc, mpeg-dash

I generated the segments and MPD manifest in DASH format with two different tools:

- [nginx-rtmp-module with DASH option](http://www.helping-squad.com/nginx-rtmp-hls-or-dash-streaming/)
- [edash-packager](https://github.com/google/edash-packager/blob/master/README.md)

Now I can't find a way to play the stream back...

I've read VLC should be from version 2.1 able to take it as input. If I go to Preferences/Input codecs/Stream Filter, I can select Dynamic Adaptive Streaming über HTTP but then when I try to open the manifest file I receive the message saying the format of that file is not recognized.
I haven't been able to play it from an online source as a network stream either.

I got this results on Windows 7 and on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test playback, a web-based player is the easiest solution. There is a free version of [bitdash](http://www.dash-player.com/), which I had running with the NGINX DASH module myself and it worked without problems.

There is also the [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js) project but I don't know if it works with NGINX.